# Running a background job in Windows

Tags: windows

On Unix, I can easily give long-running jobs to the `at` daemon which will execute them in a non-interactive session with my user credentials and at a lower priority and report the command output to me via mail after completion.

Is there a similar mechanism for Windows that can do this?

Specifically, I often have to clean up a directory full of temporary files, which takes about two hours with `cmd /c rmdir /s /q …`. I would really like to log out and go home at this point, but as the running command is attached to my logon session, this would interrupt the deletion process.

Comment: There's no easy way to do this. You can create a task using task scheduler and use the system account so you do not have to be logged in, but its not as easy as the at deamon. Note, `at` used to be part of windows, but was deprecated somewhere down the road.

Comment: How's about to create a service with `sc` command? You may make it automatic startup type.

Answer (score 1):

I remember turning some app that wasn't a service into a service using a little utility called SRVSTART. At the [author's page](http://www.rozanski.org.uk/software), we read:

> SRVSTART.EXE
>
> Synopsis. SRVSTART.EXE is a Win32 executable and DLL which allows you to run commands as if they were Windows NT services. It also has some features to enhance the running of ordinary console commands (prompting for parameters etc). The DLL can be used on its own to build a service without having to write any service management code.
>
> SRVSTART.EXE operates in one of two modes.
>
> - It can be used to run an ordinary command (executable program batch file). In this command mode, SRVSTART.EXE can prompt the user for the values of command-line parameters such as passwords.
> - It can be used to run an executable program in the context of a Windows NT service (service mode). SRVSTART.EXE will itself handle all of the interactions with the NT Service Control Manager (SCM). It is not necessary for the program to include any service management code.

Seeing as someone [wrote an article about this little tool](https://www.howtogeek.com/50786/using-srvstart-to-run-any-application-as-a-windows-service/) not so long ago, I gather it is still usable today.

Comment: Windows has `sc` which can do the same. Saves anyone from installing extra programs. Otherwise, the answer is ok. so a +1 anyway.